# A surjective homomorphism and normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I'm reviewing group theory for a comprehensive exam and this question came up.

Suppose I have two groups $G$ and $K$ and $\varphi$, a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $K$.  How can I prove that if $N$ is normal in $K$, then $\varphi^{-1}(N)$ is normal in $G$?

Here's my sketch: suppose that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $K$, then for each $k = \varphi(g) \in K$, we have the following:

$N = kNk^{-1}$

$\varphi^{-1}(N) = \varphi^{-1}(kNk^{-1}) = \varphi^{-1}(k)\varphi^{-1}(N)\varphi^{-1}(k^{-1})) = g\varphi^{-1}(N)g^{-1}$

Which, hopefully, shows that $\varphi^{-1}(N)$ is normal in $G$.  I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything major in my proof.

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the pre-image of a subgroup under a homomorphism a group?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476508/is-the-pre-image-of-a-subgroup-under-a-homomorphism-a-group), and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510633/the-preimage-of-a-normal-subgroup-under-a-group-homomorphism-is-normal).

Comment: @Dietrich: Definitely not your first one: here the question is whether the pre-image is normal, not whether it’s a group. Your second one is a duplicate of the underlying question; the next question is whether the proposed arguments are sufficiently similar for the answer to be useful, and (somewhat unusually) that seems actually to be the case: both OPs made essentially the same mistake.

Comment: Just a couple of comments: 1) it doesn't seem like you used surjectivity anywhere, and 2) the preimage of $k$ need not be a single element (multiple elements may map to $k$, as we do not have injectivity).

Comment: You’ve made essentially the same mistake as the person who posted [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237476/have-alphag-to-h-if-a-subgroup-u-is-normal-in-h-prove-the-pre-image-of); I addressed it in my answer to that question.